# create a new variable based on a condition of particular rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Given:

```
df <- data.frame(indicator = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 var = c("go", "turn", "stop", "go", "turn", "turn", "go", "turn", "turn", "turn", "turn",
                         "go", "turn", "turn", "go", "stop", "go", "turn", "turn", "go"))
df
#    indicator  var
# 1          0   go
# 2          0 turn
# 3          0 stop
# 4          0   go
# 5          0 turn
# 6          1 turn
# 7          0   go
# 8          0 turn
# 9          1 turn
# 10         0 turn
# 11         0 turn
# 12         0   go
# 13         0 turn
# 14         0 turn
# 15         0   go
# 16         0 stop
# 17         0   go
# 18         1 turn
# 19         0 turn
# 20         0   go
```

I want to create a variable around rows where `indicator == 1` and where there are a run of `turn`s in `var`. If there are a run of `turn`s but no `indicator == 1` within them, I ignore them (e.g., row 13, 14).

The output I want is:

```
#    indicator  var new_var
# 1          0   go       0
# 2          0 turn       0
# 3          0 stop       0
# 4          0   go       0
# 5          0 turn       1
# 6          1 turn       1
# 7          0   go       0
# 8          0 turn       2
# 9          1 turn       2
# 10         0 turn       2
# 11         0 turn       2
# 12         0   go       0
# 13         0 turn       0
# 14         0 turn       0
# 15         0   go       0
# 16         0 stop       0
# 17         0   go       0
# 18         1 turn       3
# 19         0 turn       3
# 20         0   go       0
```

Any ideas for a flexible approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0

df |>
  group_by(new_var = consecutive_id(var)) |>
  mutate(new_var = var == "turn" & any(indicator == 1),
         add = row_number() == 1 & new_var) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(new_var  = new_var + (cumsum(add) - 1)  * new_var, .keep = "unused")
```

**Output**

```
   indicator var   new_var
       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1         0 go          0
 2         0 turn        0
 3         0 stop        0
 4         0 go          0
 5         0 turn        1
 6         1 turn        1
 7         0 go          0
 8         0 turn        2
 9         1 turn        2
10         0 turn        2
11         0 turn        2
12         0 go          0
13         0 turn        0
14         0 turn        0
15         0 go          0
16         0 stop        0
17         0 go          0
18         1 turn        3
19         0 turn        3
20         0 go          0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can use `consecutive_id()` + `dense_rank()`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(new_var = consecutive_id(var)) %>%
  mutate(new_var = if_else(var == "turn" & any(indicator == 1), new_var, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(new_var = dense_rank(new_var) - 1)

# # A tibble: 20 × 3
#    indicator var   new_var
#        <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#  1         0 go          0
#  2         0 turn        0
#  3         0 stop        0
#  4         0 go          0
#  5         0 turn        1
#  6         1 turn        1
#  7         0 go          0
#  8         0 turn        2
#  9         1 turn        2
# 10         0 turn        2
# 11         0 turn        2
# 12         0 go          0
# 13         0 turn        0
# 14         0 turn        0
# 15         0 go          0
# 16         0 stop        0
# 17         0 go          0
# 18         1 turn        3
# 19         0 turn        3
# 20         0 go          0
```

Comment: +1 On a dataset of 3 million rows, this took ~53 secs vs only ~8 secs for @LMc answer. I thought the bottle neck was due to `dense_rank` but it is actually `if_else` - changing to `ifelse` reduces the time to ~8 secs too. Although I didnt include it in my example, I had to do this over groups and found that if a group had only 1 row with a `turn` and `indicator == 1`, then this solution did not catch it - just in case anyone else is using this!